# NSURLConnection Intermittent Failure iPhone Device On LAN

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using NSURLConnection to communicate with a web service on my LAN. When using the Xcode Simulator everything works as expected. However, when using an iPhone the connection mostly times out (but not always).

The iPhone is connected to the LAN via wifi. I can consistently browse the web server (which is hosting the web service) using Safari.

However, the app mostly fails. It returns in the `didFailWithError` function reporting "The request timed out".

The app will intermittently succeed (behaving exactly as expected). I can see no pattern for success or failure. It may fail several times and then succeed and then fail again (without restarting the app). I estimate a 90%+ failure rate.

The web service *always* receives the request and *always* responds. It appears the failure happens with the device not receiving or handling the response.

I can see no obvious problem with my network. Certainly there is no IP address clash.

I am completely new to apps, Apple, Xcode and iPhone. So this could be something really very obvious to you. Any ideas what I could look at to resolve this?

The environment I'm currently using for development is as follows:

- Mac OS X (10.7.4)
- Xcode 4 (targetting 4.3)
- iPhone 3GS (5.1.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously I cannot give you the absolute answer, but can hopefully help you track the problem down.

First, you want vet your web service. Put a JPEG image in a public Dropbox folder. Now try to download that image with your code as well as view it with Safari. If Safari works but your code does not, then you know your code is the problem.

If both fail then the phone may have a bad transceiver, or your WIFI network may be flakey. Take the phone to some public WIFI location and redo the test. If both still fail on a second network, the phone is probably defective.

If in all cases Safari works but your code does not, then please post as much of your code as possible. Also, if using the asynchronous interface, are you getting redirected? Asked for credentials? Etc. I would be inclined to add every NSURLConnection delegate method and at least add a log so you know what's going on - that is log all responses. You can also get the html return code from the response:

```
assert([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]);
NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response; 
htmlStatus = [httpResponse statusCode];
if(htmlStatus != 200) NSLog(@"Server Response code %i", htmlStatus);
```

Comment: Yes my code is the problem. The phone wifi works fine at the local cafe. Safari works consistently on my LAN. I wrote a quick simple test app (requesting a text response from the ws) which works consistently. My failing app has two views each with their own NSURLConnection. Although the app fails with only one active connection I will start with refactoring the NSURLConnection code into a single class. Thanks. Answer accepted but any further tips appreciated. e.g. Should I only ever have one query running at a time? It works with two on the simulator but...

Comment: I am querying asynchronously and logging in every delegate method. There is no authorisation involved. I guess I need to have only one instance of NSURLConnection. That's what I will try now. Please say if that sounds a reasonable direction to go or if anything else springs to mind.

Comment: Yes, you use one NSURLConnection per web transaction. In my app I have literally hundreds of fetches queued up in a NSOperationQueue, and its working perfectly. If you want to see a quick and easy way to do this look at https://github.com/dhoerl/NSOperation-WebFetches-MadeEasy - this is about as easy a technique to use you can find. That project builds a demo app you can run.